# Getting errors when using manipulation to solve equations

Tags: function-construction, manipulate

I tried to do the manipulation, but I ran into a problem. I have two parameters, but i want to change only one it's ϕ0. But i have mistake that Cut2 which respond for the changing this parametr is Unknown:

```
"Unknown option \!\(\"Cut2\"\) for Simple."
```

My code:

```
ClearAll[Simple]
Options[Simple] = {Cut1 -> 0, Cut2 -> 0};
Simple[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{kit1 = OptionValue[Cut1], 
kit2 = OptionValue[Cut2]}, 
N[-Cos[kit1]^2 + 4 Cos[kit1]^2*Sin[kit1]^2*Cos[kit2]^2 - 
1.5 Sin[kit2]^8*(0.3 + Sin[kit1]^2*Cos[kit2]^2) - 0.5*Sin[kit2]*Sin[kit1]]]

Clear[rmt1];
Clear[En];
Options[En] = {dynamic -> Simple[]};
En[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{tblEnDen, kyts1, indx, rmtEn, kyts2, 
rmt1 = OptionValue[dynamic]}, tblEnDen = Table[{0, 0}, {361}];
For[indx = 1, indx <= 361, indx++, kyts1 = 1 (indx - 1);
rmtEn = rmt1[Cut1 -> kyts1 Degree];
tblEnDen[[indx, 1]] = kyts1;
tblEnDen[[indx, 2]] = rmtEn;
];
ListPlot[
tblEnDen,
Frame -> True,
FrameLabel -> {Style["θ0", FontSize -> 16], 
Style["Energy ()", FontSize -> 16]},
PlotRange -> All,
Joined -> True,
Mesh -> All
 ]
]

Manipulate[En[dynamic -> Simple[Cut2 -> kyts2 Degree]], "Select Options:", 
"Value of ϕ0:", {{kyts2, 90.0, "Degree"}, 0.0, 360.0, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

After errors were corrected and running the prog., the graph doesn't work. 
[image]
But if i write the same code without manipulate it works. Code which works:

```
gEnDen = 271;

tblEnDen = Table[{0, 0}, {gEnDen}];

For[indx = 1, indx <= gEnDen, indx++, kyts = 1 (indx - 1);
rmtRF = Simple[Сut1 -> kyts Degree, Сut2 -> 45 Degree];
tblEnDen[[indx, 1]] = kyts;
tblEnDen[[indx, 2]] = rmtRF;
]
ListPlot[tblEnDen, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{"En", ""}, {"θ0 (Degree)", ""}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 15}, Mesh -> All]
```

And the result is:
[image]
Here i can change Сut2 which is ϕ0 and after compilation ended the graph is changing. The same thing i want to get from manipulating but in dynamic.

Comment: Look at `FullForm@Options@Simple`: The "C" of `Cut1`/`Cut2` is not an ordinary "C", but rather a [Cyrillic capital Es](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5C:0421)

Comment: @LukasLang, Thank you, errors are gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the way you handle the mixing of options for `Simple`. If you look at the options of `En`, you'll notice that `Simple[]` is already evaluated:

```
Options[En]
(* {dynamic -> -1.} *)
```

The situation is similar when you specify another value for the `dynamic` option. You could try to prevent evaluation of the option and manipulate it this way, but I would propose the following, easier change:

Instead of specifying `Simple[opts]` for `dynamic`, only specify `opts`. You can then easily add more options and once everything is ready, pass it to `Simple`.

The following shows how this can be implemented:

```
ClearAll[Simple]
Options[Simple] = {Cut1 -> 0, Cut2 -> 0};
Simple[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {kit1 = OptionValue[Cut1], kit2 = OptionValue[Cut2]},
  N[-Cos[kit1]^2 + 4 Cos[kit1]^2*Sin[kit1]^2*Cos[kit2]^2
   - 1.5 Sin[kit2]^8*(0.3 + Sin[kit1]^2*Cos[kit2]^2) - 0.5*Sin[kit2]*Sin[kit1]]
]

Clear[rmt1];
Clear[En];
Options[En] = {dynamic -> {}};
En[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {tblEnDen, kyts1, indx, rmtEn, kyts2, rmt1 = OptionValue[dynamic]},
  tblEnDen = Table[{0, 0}, {361}];
  For[indx = 1, indx <= 361, indx++, kyts1 = 1 (indx - 1);
   rmtEn = Simple[rmt1, Cut1 -> kyts1 Degree];
   tblEnDen[[indx, 1]] = kyts1;
   tblEnDen[[indx, 2]] = rmtEn;];
  ListPlot[tblEnDen,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {Style["θ0", FontSize -> 16], Style["Energy ()", FontSize -> 16]},
    PlotRange -> All,
    Joined -> True,
    Mesh -> All
  ]
]

Manipulate[
  En[dynamic -> {Cut2 -> kyts2 Degree}], "Select Options:", "Value of ϕ0:",
  {{kyts2, 90.0, "Degree"}, 0.0, 360.0, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
]
```

[image]

There are only three changes compared to your code:

```
(* options of En *)
Options[En] = {dynamic -> {}};

(* adding of second option *)
rmtEn = Simple[rmt1, Cut1 -> kyts1 Degree];

(* inside Manipulate *)
En[dynamic -> {Cut2 -> kyts2 Degree}], …]
```

#### Additional comments

Instead of `For`, I'd suggest using `Table` directly. This leads to significantly cleaner looking code:

```
Clear[rmt1];
Clear[En];
Options[En] = {dynamic -> {}};
En[OptionsPattern[]] := Module[
  {tblEnDen, kyts1, indx, rmtEn, kyts2, rmt1 = OptionValue[dynamic]},
  tblEnDen = Table[
    {
      kyts1 = 1 (indx - 1),
      Simple[rmt1, Cut1 -> kyts1 Degree]
    },
    {indx, 1, 361}
  ];
  ListPlot[tblEnDen,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {Style["θ0", FontSize -> 16], Style["Energy ()", FontSize -> 16]},
    PlotRange -> All,
    Joined -> True,
    Mesh -> All
  ]
]
```